# Вызов метода destroy через запрос

Tags: ruby, сервер, ruby-on-rails

В целях обучения написал простейший сервер на Ruby on Rails, суть - отправляю запрос `localhost:3000/object/new?name=example` - добавляется соответствующая запись типа object с заданным параметром name. Мне необходимо, чтобы аналогичным образом можно было удалить запись. Для этого был подкорректирован метод destroy

```
  def destroy
    @object = Object.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to objects_path
  end
```

и опробован запрос `localhost:3000/objects/1/destroy`, который не привёл к желаемому результату (ошибка Routing Error). Как правильно делать запрос, и/или что ещё надо исправить?

upd: 
routes.rb:

```
Test::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :objects
  root :to => 'objects#index'
end
```

Comment: У запросов есть методы. Когда вы открываете ссылку в браузере ответ получается методом GET. Для того чтобы удалить вам нужен метод DELETE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как запрос отправляете? Если просто через строку адреса в браузере, то запрос передается как GET, а должен как DELETE. Это достигается при помощи отправки запроса при помощи кнопки, или ссылки.

И можно содержимое routes.rb посмотреть?

**UPD**

Вы все правильно описали в routes.rb. Дело в том что есть такая модель как REST, она определяет то посредством каких запросов манипулировать данными. С нашей моделью мы можем делать такие вещи:

Create - создание объекта
Read - чтение объекта (вывод на страничку например, или отображение в виде XML/JSON)
Update - обновление некоторых полей объекта
Delete - удаление объекта

Это называется CRUD модель.
Мы общаемся с приложением через HTTP-протокол, он использует запросы разных типов
POST - create
GET - read
PUT - update
DELETE - delete

Перейдите в директорию с вашим проектом в терминале и выполните такую команду

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

на экран будет выведен список всех URL-ов на которые можно отправлять запросы, и также будет написано какой URL  обрабатывает тот или иной тип запроса.

Отправка запроса с нужним типом уже не ваша заобта, а забота разработчика стороннего приложения. 
Ваша же задача верно эти запросы обрабатывать.

ЗЫ. если как-то сумбурно написал или где ошибся, то прошу простить, голова другим занята.

Comment: Да, через строку браузера, думал для этого сгодится GET-запрос. Вообще, моя конечная цель - отправлять запрос из клиентского приложения, вы не могли бы поподробнее растолковать о DELETE-запросе для таких условий?

routes.rb:

Test::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :objects
  root :to => 'objects#index'
end

Comment: обновил ответ